# Storing API keys in a Flutter Firebase app? Do I need to hide them? How?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am developing an iOS/Android app with Flutter and Firebase (mainly Cloud FireStore and Firebase Auth). According to the [Firebase documentation/example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core#-example-tab-), they just put the API key along with the googleAppID straight into the app's source code. This to me seems very insecure, but at the same time I did hear that dart is compiled AOT. So what is the best practice for putting the Firebase API keys in a Flutter app?

Any response is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example is usually not followed. The key is stored in the `google-services.json` file or the equivalent for iOS that should be added to the project following the Firebase setup instructions. This removes the issue with people easily knowing your key. I don't believe it would matter if someone did however as the key is intended to be public.

[Setup Instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

Comment: I see. Thank you! Can you provide a link (if there is any) for detailed instructions, please?

Comment: @David Yes I added the setup link for Firebase for Flutter. You have to follow both the iOS and android instructions

Comment: Ah, thanks! It turns out that I have already followed those instructions, but I didn't know that by doing that I wouldn't need to include the API keys in the dart code. Just checked the `plist` file and it does have my API keys. Thank you!

Comment: Just one last question, how does this approach make it more secure?

Comment: @David The key isn't directly in the code so there isn't a need to obfuscate it. I'm not sure that this makes it much more difficult, but as I said, the API key is intended to be publicly available.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: @David No problem.

Comment: Great answer Christopher. @David: The configuration data is shared equally between both approaches, but that is **not** a security concerns. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Thanks! @FrankvanPuffelen So I guess I should always enforce security with Cloud FireStore security rules.

Comment: @David Yeah you should always do that and do it for other services that you use as well as they are applicable.

Comment: Ok! Thank y'all!